# Is it possible to filter out my own app from "picking from gallery"?

Tags: android, mobile, gallery, android-gallery

So I have defined my app to accept other apps to open it as Gallery to pick a photo.

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PICK" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.GET_CONTENT" />

            <data android:mimeType="image/*" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.OPENABLE" />
        </intent-filter>
```

However, inside my app, I also want to allow users to pick images from gallery.

```
Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, REQ_CODE_PICK_FROM_GALLERY);
```

As you may think of, the problem is my app appears in the chooser dialog. Is it possible to filter my own app out?

Thanks.

Comment: If your app is able to do something, why should it ask for others ?

Comment: because my app is used to do something on top of the others...

Answer (score 2):

Finally I solved by using this piece of code.
https://gist.github.com/mediavrog/5625602

```
// Usage:
// blacklist
String[] blacklist = new String[]{"com.any.package", "net.other.package"};
// your share intent
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.setType("text/plain");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "some text");
intent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "a subject");
// ... anything else you want to add
// invoke custom chooser
startActivity(generateCustomChooserIntent(intent, blacklist));

// Method:
private Intent generateCustomChooserIntent(Intent prototype, String[] forbiddenChoices) {
    List<Intent> targetedShareIntents = new ArrayList<Intent>();
    List<HashMap<String, String>> intentMetaInfo = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    Intent chooserIntent;

    Intent dummy = new Intent(prototype.getAction());
    dummy.setType(prototype.getType());
    List<ResolveInfo> resInfo = getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(dummy, 0);

    if (!resInfo.isEmpty()) {
        for (ResolveInfo resolveInfo : resInfo) {
            if (resolveInfo.activityInfo == null || Arrays.asList(forbiddenChoices).contains(resolveInfo.activityInfo.packageName))
                continue;

            HashMap<String, String> info = new HashMap<String, String>();
            info.put("packageName", resolveInfo.activityInfo.packageName);
            info.put("className", resolveInfo.activityInfo.name);
            info.put("simpleName", String.valueOf(resolveInfo.activityInfo.loadLabel(getPackageManager())));
            intentMetaInfo.add(info);
        }

        if (!intentMetaInfo.isEmpty()) {
            // sorting for nice readability
            Collections.sort(intentMetaInfo, new Comparator<HashMap<String, String>>() {
                @Override
                public int compare(HashMap<String, String> map, HashMap<String, String> map2) {
                    return map.get("simpleName").compareTo(map2.get("simpleName"));
                }
            });

            // create the custom intent list
            for (HashMap<String, String> metaInfo : intentMetaInfo) {
                Intent targetedShareIntent = (Intent) prototype.clone();
                targetedShareIntent.setPackage(metaInfo.get("packageName"));
                targetedShareIntent.setClassName(metaInfo.get("packageName"), metaInfo.get("className"));
                targetedShareIntents.add(targetedShareIntent);
            }

            chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(targetedShareIntents.remove(targetedShareIntents.size() - 1), getString(R.string.share));
            chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, targetedShareIntents.toArray(new Parcelable[]{}));
            return chooserIntent;
        }
    }

    return Intent.createChooser(prototype, getString(R.string.share));
}
```